# R Programming - Generating All Combinations of Multiple Lists

Tags: r

I'm reasonably new to programming and learning as I go. What I am trying to do is generate all possible combinations of multiple vectors, there are are plenty of answers to similar questions on the forum but nothing that seems to match my issue.

I have 4 separate lists (length will change depending on inputs but I don't think that will cause an issue other than increase the number of outputs), ie

```
 a<-c("a","b","c")
 b<-c("d","e","f","g","h")
 c<-c("i","j")
 d<-c("k","l","m")
```

Now, I need all possible combinations which include

- 2 items from each of a & d
- 4 items from b
- just 1 item from c

I've tried `combn(a,a,b,b,b,b,c,d,d)` but that doesn't give the right answer
   (clearly). I've also tried `combn(combn(a,2),combn(b,4).......)` but
   this doesn't seem to give the correct result either (plus the
   resulting list only gives 4 values per line item and not the required
   9).

Can anyone help, what I want to see is a list something like

```
1  a b d e f g i k l  
2  a b d e f g i k m
etc ................
```

Appreciate your time

Answer (score 3):

`expand.grid` may be useful here:

```
a<-c("a","b","c")
b<-c("d","e","f","g","h")
c<-c("i","j")  
d<-c("k","l","m")

expand.grid(a,a,b,b,b,b,c,d,d)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback NBATrends, I dont believe that would just give the combinations though? I've tried that previously and believe it gave duplications, ie for the first two variables it could give aa or bb where as the only combinations possible should be ab, bc & ac.